# Convert NSData to byte array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdata

I want to convert the NSData into byte array and given below is the code that i have used

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(recipeImage.image);
    NSUInteger len = [imageData length];
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [imageData bytes], len);
    NSLog(@"%8s",byteData);
```

But its giving me an error when i post the byteData to the webservice which is given below

"Server was unable to process request. ---> Parameter is not valid."

and when i print the byteData this is what i get in the console

```
âPNG
```

I tried searching the docs for NSData and found the getBytes method but that too was not of any use i was still getting the same error.

Could you please let me know from the code above as in where i am wrong or what mistake i am making in converting the data into byte array

Edit: I have tried using the

```
[imageData getBytes:&byteData length:length];
```

Its giving me a bad access error

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Get the pixel data from the picture?

Comment: Remove the `&` and the bad access error will go away.  I don't see the point of this code anyway - why not leave the data inside the `NSData` object and avoid the expense of additional memory and copying data?

Comment: You can also simply reference the byte array as is using `Byte *byteData = imageData.bytes;`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(recipeImage.image);  
NSUInteger len = [imageData length];
Byte *byteData= (Byte*)malloc(len);
[imageData  getBytes:byteData length:len];
```

Comment: @ParagBafna what parameter i have to send to webservice (imageData/len/byteData)?

Comment: Needless to say, if you use this `malloc` pattern, make sure you all `free` when done with the `byteData` or else you'll leak.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is somewhere totally different.

You are sending data to a web service, and that fails. **Show us how you send the data to the web service**. Converting NSData to a byte array is absolutely pointless. imageData.bytes is as good a byte array as you are ever going to get.