# Objective C converting NSData with hex value to int

Tags: objective-c, int, nsdata

I have a `NSData` with a hex value inside e.g. `<EC>`.

Now I need to convert this value into an `int` variable to get `int x = -20`.

Ideas?

Comment: How did the value get encoded into a NSData object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696391/convert-nsdata-to-byte-array to see how to get byte values from `NSData`. From there you should no problem processing whichever byte you need.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getBytes` to extract that byte from the `NSData`:

```
uint8_t byte;
[data getBytes:&byte length:1];
```

If you really need that in an `int`, then grab it from that `uint8_t` variable:

```
int x = byte;
```

---

As an aside, if you really need this `0xec` value interpreted as `-20` rather than `236`, you can use `int8_t` instead of `uint8_t`, and the sign of this byte value will be preserved. Frequently, though, when dealing with binary data, we deal with unsigned bytes, rather than signed integers, but it just depends upon what this binary `NSData` represents.

Comment: I was just typing the exact same thing.